# C - function parameters and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, pass-by-value

Consider two cases of calling a function:

```
void Convert(int number, int **staticPointer)
{
    int * dynamicPointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *dynamicPointer = number;
    *staticPointer = dynamicPointer;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;

    Convert(5, &p);

    printf("The number is: %d", *p);

    free(p);
}
```

The above works beautifully with no problem.

Now the case below:

```
void Convert(int number, int *staticPointer)
{
    int * dynamicPointer = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *dynamicPointer = number;
    staticPointer = dynamicPointer;
}

int main()
{
    int *p;

    Convert(5, p);

    printf("The number is: %d", *p);

    free(p);
}
```

This causes SEGFAULT. Notice that I do call the function in different ways with different parameters, and I do understand that the difference is in the calling of the function.

Can somebody please explain to me why I have to call the function as in the first example, and why the other example doesn't work (it crashes in main)?

The purpose of my program is to reference a static pointer to a specific memory address through a function.

Comment: The first one changes the pointer in the `main()` function; the second changes the copy of the pointer in the `Convert()` function, but doesn't change the pointer in the `main()` function, so the pointer in `main()` is uninitialized and you are lucky that you got a crash to tell you are doing it wrong (that wasn't guaranteed).

Answer (score 1):

C uses pass by value for function parameter passing.

- In the first case, by passing the *address of the pointer* `p`, you were able to change the pointer itself. So, im `main()`, your *changes* are *reflected*.
- In he second case, the pointer *itself* cannot be changed, as it itself is passed-by-value. Once you return from the `Convert()` function, any changes made to `p` will be lost. So, in `main()`, you'll be accessing invalid memory (`*p`) which nvokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Hence the crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you're changing:

- Function type
- Function invocation

Since you want to modify the pointers value, you have to provide a pointer to the pointer to int.

See [resources](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx8.html) on pointers to pointers.